# How to remove CRLF in Vi editor

Tags: bash, unix, vi

I am copying  "E)H@McQfTjWnZr4t7w!z%C*F-JaNdRgU"  to a file using vi editor. The file size should be 32 bytes but its 33bytes. I opened the same file using notepad++ and found that CRLF is being added at the end of the text.

How can i remove CRLF in vi editor.

Answer (score 7):

Try this in vi

```
:set noendofline binary
:w
```

This will remove any line endings from the file and give you the 32 byte file you're expecting to see.

Also note you can use these other commands to change the line ending types in vi as well.

```
:set ff=dos
:w
```

Or

```
:set ff=unix
:w
```

You can also do this from the commandline to perform on multiple files with something like

```
for file in $files; do
    vi +':w ++ff=unix' +':q' $file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, without using vi:

```
~$ echo -n 'E)H@McQfTjWnZr4t7w!z%C*F-JaNdRgU' > t
~$ ls -l t
-rw-r--r-- 1 niglesias niglesias 32 Jun  8 14:07 t
```